# Convert an array of objects to JSON

Tags: python, json, web.py

I am using `web.py` to make a simple web service, to return an `array of object`. I was constructing a `JSON String` manually, now I want to replace it with a `JSON Library`. I am trying to use `JSON` for this purpose.

This is how I am doing it:

```
return json.dump(schedules.__dict__)
```

`schedules` is a list of `schedule`. This is how a `schedule` object looks like:

```
class Schedule:

    def __init__(self):
        self._matchDate = None
        self._matchTime = None

    @property
    def matchDate(self):
        return self._matchDate

    @property
    def matchTime(self):
        return self._matchTime

    @matchTime.setter
    def matchTime(self, value):
        self._matchTime = value

    @matchDate.setter
    def matchDate(self, value):
        self._matchDate = value
```

This is the error which I get:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> at /Schedule
'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'
Python  /home/faizan/PycharmProjects/Soccer/Rest.py in GET, line 24
Web     GET http://localhost:8080/Schedule
```

How do I go about serializing the objects in JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the proper approach here is a custom JSONEncoder that knows how to handle all your special types. Then you can do `json.dump(schedules, cls=MyJSONEncoder)`. Here's an example for [extending JSONEncoder](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (search for "Extending JSONEncoder").

Answer (score 0):

I guess that JSON supports only POD formats and therefore you should use other methods of serialization for your complex objects. Try [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Pickle isn't an option, here, because this is a web service.